# Problem with quicklisp slime-helper

Tags: emacs

I'm running EMACS 27.1 on Ubuntu 22.04. I installed a new EMACS, and have been slowly making a configuration file. After I added the line

(load (expand-file-name "~/quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))

when I start EMACS I get the warning

Warning (bytecomp): Unused lexical variable 'start'

The token 'start' doesn't occur in slime-helper.el. What should I look at next?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by Emacs 27.1, at least the version in the package from Ubuntu's Universe repository, bytecompiles a lot of files on startup. I don't know which file, and I don't know how to make Emacs NOT bytecompile everything on startup. I solved my problem by uninstalling Emacs 27.1 and installing 28.1 from the PPA.